# Change text width for parts of the page

Tags: geometry, textwidth

Is it possible to change text width in the middle of a page? If I use `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` this forces a page break. The package `changepage` and the command `\adjustwidth` work for the MWE but give an error in my real .tex file, clashing with `microtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=5cm,textheight=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

This is a sentence that should have a 5 cm textwidth. And now we pass to 10 cm
\newgeometry{textwidth=10cm,}
\lipsum[1]
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need to change `textwidth` itself? You could also set `leftmargin` or `rightmargin` in a group to shrink the text of a particular part of the page.

Comment: use a standard `quote` environment or adjustwidth which is similar. if some code gives an error, ask about the error, with an example

Comment: Thanks. With the [strict] option changepage does not give me error...  And I also appreciate the idea of changing margins. So it is solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To spell out and a wee bit extend and clarify your comment.

The `adjustwidth` macro of `changepage` package can use also in two side documents:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} % <---
\usepackage[textwidth=5cm,textheight=15cm]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}

This is a odd side page. Here the text has width of 5 cm.
\newpage
This is a even side page. Normally here the text width is 5 cm,

\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-5cm} % <---
\itshape
But we can change width by use of \verb+adjustwidth*+ macro, which locally push paragraph's outside margin so, that the \verb+\textwidth+ become 10 cm wide.

\lipsum[66]
\end{adjustwidth*}

And here the text width is again 5 cm. As before the use of the \verb+adjustwidth*+ macro.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the cases, when your document is just one sided, than you not need to load `changepage` with `strict` option. Now the `adjustwidth` can be used as

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{-5cm} % <---
\itshape
But we can change width by use of \verb+adjustwidth+ macro, which locally push paragraph's right margin so, that the \verb+\textwidth+ become 10 cm wide.

\lipsum[66]
\end{adjustwidth}
```

and text on any page will protrude out of the right pages text borders:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change width of lines in a single paragraph, then use `\parshape` primitive or `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` primitive registers.

The width of the paragraph itself is given by the `\hsize` register and `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` registers gives the space before and after each line in the paragraph.

The mentioned primitive registers are used by TeX internal paragraph builder when it builds the paagraph, i.e. at the `\par` command (which is typically inserted at empty lines by the TeX token processor).

Answer (score 2):

Even if the OP marked the question as solved in a comment, here two working solutions, for the case someone else has a similar problem.

Without additional package (`geometry` only for simple show the margin and setting `textwidth`) you could set the `leftskip` and `rightskip` (here as `newenvironment`) as mentioned by **wipet**:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm, showframe]{geometry}
\newenvironment{smallmargin}{%
\par\setlength\leftskip{2.5cm}%
\setlength\rightskip\leftskip}{%
\par}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{smallmargin}
\blindtext
\end{smallmargin}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Or with `adjuswidth` environment provided by package `changepage` (which offers additional options), as suggested by **David Carlisle**:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}
\blindtext
\end{adjustwidth}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! All comment are useful. The answer based on tex primitives helps in learning, but for my need I will use the changepage package. My mistake was not to change the commands for the 2 page book class. Now it takes care automatically of left and right pages, and it seems to work well.